# Converting yyyymm date to yyyyqn SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert date from format yyyymm like 202001 (2020 jan), 202002 (feb 2020) etc. to yyyyqn format for eg.

```
@currdate (yyyymm) Expected format
-----------------------------------
202001              2020Q1
202005              2020Q2 
202012              2020Q4   and so on
```

This is the query I tried:

```
declare @currdate nvarchar(6)
set @currdate = (SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyyMM'))

select 
    left(@currdate, 4) as year, 
    cast(year as char(4)) + 'Q' + (select right(@currdate, 2) as month)
```

Error:

> Invalid column name 'year'

Comment: Use CONVERT(DATE, @currdate + ‘01’, 112) to get back to a DATE type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Comment: i need q word in middle as mentioned

Comment: “The problem is that this currdate is not date type, so i cannot use datepart etc..” Well, now that you have the date, use DATEPART etc.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.

Comment: That’s a bad local syntax usage then. Note that the quotes put in comments by iOS are “pretty”.

Comment: pls correct my query nd my error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a column alias in select  you must repeat the code

```
declare @currdate nvarchar(6)
set @currdate =(SELECT FORMAT(GetDate(),'yyyyMM'))
select left(@currdate,4) as year, cast(left(@currdate,4) as char(4)) 
 + 'Q' + (select right(@currdate,2) as month)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it like this (adding `2` to any value between `1-12` and then applying integer division by `3` will give your desired result in the range `1-4`)

```
declare @d char(6) = '202001'

SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(@d,4),'Q',(RIGHT(@d,2)+2)/3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to convert `@currdate` to a date if you concat `01` to it and then use format 112 (ISO). Then you can use [`DATEPART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to extract the quarter and put that in a `CONCAT` with the left 4 characters and a `Q`:

```
declare @currdate nvarchar(6)
set @currdate = '202001'
select concat(left(@currdate, 4), 'Q', datepart(quarter, convert(date, concat(@currdate, '01'), 112)))
set @currdate = '202008'
select concat(left(@currdate, 4), 'Q', datepart(quarter, convert(date, concat(@currdate, '01'), 112)))
```

Alternatively you can just divide the month by 3, take the `FLOOR` and add 1:

```
select concat(left(@currdate, 4), 'Q', floor(right(@currdate, 2) / 3) + 1)
```

In both cases the output is:

```
2020Q1
2020Q3
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d8aeb6c8b24c5ca65e471e276e6c8d1b)